# Add additional dependencies to an exisiting EAR

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-ear-plugin

I have 2 separate maven projects.

The first builds a lot of artifacts, and packages them up into an EAR.
This is the standard product.

The second project is bespoke for a customer, and builds some additional
JAR files. I need a mechanism to insert these 2 JAR files into the lib
directory of the EAR built by the first project.

Is there a nice simple way of doing this, whereby I list the artifact of
the first project in the second, so that it does not need to know how it
was put together, it simply inserts the additional JARS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the contents of another ear file in your second ear file by specifying the first ear file als dependency, but using `<type>pom</type>` instead of `ear`:

if you specify an ear dependency, transitive dependencies are not resolved (ear is defined as a container type). If you use pom instead, all dependencies of your first ear are (transitive) dependencies to the second ear, and thus included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those supplemental jar files as dependencies to your project pom and furthermore you need to add them to your [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
           [...]
           <modules>
             <jarModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
               <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
             </jarModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: That will create an EAR files with only the 2 jar files in a lib directory. How do I include the contents of the original EAR?